# Sub-sub-list disappearing in Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, sublist

I have taken over a wordpress site built by someone else (londonschoolofsamba.co.uk) and am having difficulties with sub-sub-lists disappearing in the navigation.

If I visit a page that has children, then the navigation displays the parent pages, and the children and grandchildren of that page.  If I visit one of the pages that is a child, then the navigation still displays the parent and grandchildren, but if I go to a grandchild page, then the navigation returns to displaying only the parents.

Can anyone help me to get it so that when visiting a grandchild page, that the navigation still shows the children and grandchildren, and not just the parents?

```
<?php
    $this_post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $temp = get_post_ancestors($this_post);
    if(sizeof($temp) > 0)
    {
        $this_page_id = $temp[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $this_page_id = $this_post->ID;
    }

    $home_page = get_page_by_title('Home');
    $pages = get_pages("sort_column=menu_order&parent=0&exclude=".$home_page->ID);
    foreach($pages as $page)
    {
        $classes = "menu_item";
        if($this_page_id == $page->ID)
        {
            $classes .= " selected_menu";
        }
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
            <div class="menu_item_picture">
                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID);?>"><?php echo $page->post_title;?></a>
            </div>
             <?php
                $list = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$page->ID."&depth=2&echo=0");

                if($this_page_id == $page->ID && strlen($list) >0)
                {
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php echo $list;?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Provide a code for it

Comment: Hi Tamil, I don't seem to be able to list more than two links until I have a reputation of 10?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your css , check if it displays all the menus while css is disabled ( remove or rename your stylesheet for a while )

Comment: Great thinking @farscode . Not all pages are visible in the navigation menu when CSS is disabled.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see the issue now, with the 2015 carnival grandchildren. They all display the same page. The issue is either in the template or the configuration of the permalink structure. I would need a screenshot of the permalinks page, any 2015 carnival grandchild page (where we can see its attribute + permalink settings) and the php of the template used (as defined by the pag attributes).

Comment: I've listed the php from the sidebar.php @Sotkra above.

Comment: the issue does not lie in the sidebar nor the css, its the template/loop php that is loading the wrong post. I need to see the other things I requested or else I can't get to the heart of the matter.